Use the returned value of a select list with the sum function in a query
I am using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.22.0.0.0, Product Build  20.1.0.00.13
I have a select list called P2_METRIC_NAME.  It is a list of fields in a table.  I want to use that in the sum function in a select list for a chart.  So, it would be:
select null link, 
to_char(dwh_xdate, 'Mon YYYY'), 
sum(&P2_METRIC_NAME.)
from core_performance_output_t
where dwh_xdate >= :p0_date
group by dwh_xdate
order by dwh_xdate

So, if the user selects "NET_OUTSTANDINGS" from the select list, the query should be interpreted as:
select null link,
to_char(dwh_xdate, 'Mon YYYY'),
sum(NET_OUTSTANDINGS)
from core_performance_output_t
where dwh_xdate >= :p0_date
group by dwh_xdate
order by dwh_xdate

I have tried using &P2_METRIC_NAME. and :P2_METRIC_NAME.  Attached is the error I get when I use "SUM(&P2_METRIC_NAME)".  I feel like I'm on the right track with this error but not really sure what to try next.

One more bit of information that may or may not be relevant:  The select list for :P2_METRIC_NAME is a query:
select column_name d, column_name r
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'CORE_PERFORMANCE_OUTPUT_T'
and column_name not in ('METRIC','METRIC_NAME','DWH_XDATE')
group by column_name
order by 1

The following are screenshots of two ways I have tried to make this work.  The first is my attempt to use the select list value directly into the query:

These next screenshots are when I tried to make a function that returns a query and use that as my series:

And the function syntax:


The syntax is "&" + page item name + "." , SUM(&P2_METRIC_NAME) should be SUM(&P2_METRIC_NAME.) - notice the "." at the end . See docs. For bind variables the syntax is ":" + page item name.

In SQL Developer, SUM(&P2_METRIC_NAME.) works great!  However, moving that to Apex doesn't seem to work at all.  My query for the first series in my chart is:
select null link,
to_char(dwh_xdate, 'Month'),
sum(&P2_METRIC_NAME.)
from core_performance_output_t

In your query you need to use bind variable syntax: :P2_METRIC_NAME . The substitution syntax &P2_METRIC_NAME. is for when this value is rendered in html. If this is in a chart, make sure that the P2_METRIC_NAME is in the "items to submit" attribute, else it will not pick up the selected value from the select list.

It's still not working.  I get an error that says:  Ajax call returned server error ORA-01722: invalid number for .   My query is
select null link,
to_char(dwh_xdate, 'Month'),
sum(:P2_METRIC_NAME)
from core_performance_output_t
group by dwh_xdate
order by dwh_xdate
And I do have P2_METRIC_NAME as the page item to submit.

I'm going to edit my question with screenshots.  Hopefully that will clear things up

This is a simple example based on Scott's sample schema, its emp table.
I created select list page item named P2_COLUMN that displays columns from the emp table. It submits the page when value is changed.
Then, I created a stored function which returns query that represents chart source:
create or replace function f_col (par_column in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  retval varchar2(1000);
begin
  retval := 'select deptno, sum(&P2_COLUMN.) val from emp group by deptno';
  return retval;
end;
/

Chart region's source is function body that returns SQL query:
return f_col(':P2_COLUMN');


Result is then - for two sample columns:

which looks OK to me.

If you ask

why wouldn't I directly return that query in Apex, i.e. use this:
   return 'select deptno, sum(&P2_COLUMN.) val from emp group by deptno';

as region source

the answer is: because you'd get

ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 4, column 4: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments".

error. Why? No idea, I'm not that smart.

You're welcome. Sure you can; that's what I did.

I created the stored function in SQL Developer just as you said.  And that seemed to be OK.  No errors.  However, I'm getting a "Failed to Parse SQL query error"
My function code is just as you said above except for the backslash that you have at the end.  That was giving another error.
My Chart source location is LOCAL DATABASE.  The Type is PL/SQL FUNCTION BODY RETURNING SQL QUERY.  And the SQL QUERY "return f_col(':P@_COLUMN');
I get error on line 4 column 6:  Invalid Function

What you did sounds OK. Backslash is irrelevant in this context. Could you post (copy/paste) the whole error message you get?

The full error message was "ORA 20999:  Parsing returned query results in "ORA20999:  Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 4, column 6: ORA-00919: invalid function",

I copied and pasted your function syntax from above in SQL Developer and named it F_COL.

One more thing:  Above, you said the Chart Region source is a function body.  But on the region itself, the LOCATION under SOURCE is:  LOCAL DATABASE, then TYPE is PL/SQL FUNCTION RETURNING SQL QUERY, CORRECT?

I edited the answer and posted screenshot which shows how it looks in Apex. As of ORA-00919, documentation days that cause is "You tried to call a function, but the name you used was not a valid Oracle function." (see e.g. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00919.php). So, did you create function in the same schema you're connected to in Apex? Did you enclose its name into double quotes and used mixed letter case?

It is in the same schema as the apex app.  As far as double quotes... Neither the function or the PL/SQL returning a query uses double quotes.  Not sure I follow where double quotes are supposed to be.  I appreciate your time.

Nowhere; don't use double quotes for any kind of identifiers while working with Oracle, they are evil :) I don't know why it doesn't work for you. There is something with the function (at least, that's what Oracle reports). If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com and share login credentials so that we could take a look.

I'm going to edit my question with screenshots of the function in SQL Developer and screenshots of my Apex screen.  It's probably something simple that I'm missing.

Hey.  Thanks again for your help.  I went back to the drawing board and approached it from a different angle.  I appreciate your time though.

OK. I'm glad you found the way to solve the problem.

I had to come at this a different way.  So in my query for the chart, I made a very long CASE... WHEN statement that said "IF :P0_MEASURE = 'NET_OUTSTANDINGS_COUNT' THEN SUM(NET_OUTSTANDINGS_COUNT) WHEN :P0_MEASURE = 'NET_OUTSTANDINGS_DOLLAR' THEN SUM(NET_OUTSTANDINGS_DOLLAR)" and so on and so forth.  So I'm indirectly measuring the field name in &P0_MEASURE.
